# Add comma at end of each line in text file from start

Tags: python, file, text

I have a text file that has 15 lines of sentences, like this:

```
Hello Guys
Wassap Guys
Bye Guys
```

In Python I want to open the file and add comma `,` at end of each line
Like this:

```
Hello Guys,
Wassap Guys,
Bye Guys,
```

Here's what I tried:

```
f = open("ddd.txt", "r+")
tl = f.readlines()

for i in tl:
     f.write(",\n")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply read all lines of your file and rewrite them appending a comma at the end of each line.
First you should read the file and save each of its' lines:

```
filepath = "myfile.txt"
with open(filepath) as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

Now you have created a list with every line in your file. Then, you simply rewrite it and append the comma to each line:

```
with open(filepath, "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line + ",\n")
```

Hope this was helpful!